# More Specific / Detailed WooCommerce Checkout Errors?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to have the error messages on the WooCommerce checkout page be more specific / detailed?

So instead of the generic error "Unfortunately your order cannot be processed as the originating bank/merchant has declined your transaction. Please attempt your purchase again." that it specifies whether the card is expired or the cvv number is incorrect, etc?

The generic error doesn't really help customers determine why the payment failed.

Comment: Are you using a plugin for payment gateways since the error message your describing(the one that needs changing) is not familiar to me(within WooCommerce).

Comment: I'm using a plugin for the WorldNet payment processor (https://wordpress.org/plugins/worldnet-payment-gateway/).